# How to change the Public token of the assembly

Tags: .net, dll, assemblies

I have two assemblies. One assembly is referring to the another one. I checked the manifest of first assembly and found it is referencing to the second one with some specific token key.

But I checked the token of second assembly and found that it has a different public token. So somehow I missed the correct second assembly. So I want to know is there a way I can change the second assembly's public token to the one which first assembly needs.

Also I have another second assembly also which has public token = null.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like you want to rebuild the second assembly and sign it with a different key, which would be easy if you had the source so I guess you don't?

I think it would be easier to rebuild the first assembly so that it references the second assembly you have, using the public key token that is present on the second assembly.  Easier, but not entirely straightforward.

I think you should be able to achieve it by running the first assembly through `ildasm.exe`, change the public key token on the reference to the second assembly, and then run the result through `ilasm.exe`, to produce a new version of the first assembly.

A rough outline of the steps involved...

1. Run `ildasm.exe /out=first.il first.dll` (or `first.exe`)
2. Edit `first.il` and find the **.assembly** extern block for the reference to `second.dll`
3. Change the public key token in that block
4. Run `ilasm.exe first.il` to produce `first.dll` (or `first.exe`)

Be warned, I haven't used these tools for a long time, and *never* to manipulate public key tokens in this way, so you will probably have to add some ingenuity of your own.  But on the other hand, I can't think of a reason for this approach not to work.

Comment: can you please direct me how to do that?

Comment: @Nits The process is as described above. In #4, I did add couple of switches `/res:first.res /dll` to get a DLL instead of executable. Also note: il-D-asm is different command than il-asm.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking "how can I forge second assembly's signature to make first assembly think it's original". Unless you have a keypair, used to sign the "right" assembly, you can't. So the best approach is to ask the vendor of the assemblies to provide a correct pair.

Comment: if a know the public token then also it is not possible?

Comment: Read about asymmetric cryptography and how signing works. You can sign only using private key. Public key is used for verification (you can't sign using public key).

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience you may want to change your app .Net framework so it will match dlls.